# Should I put data types in column names?

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

I've recently joined a project where our DBA has us including the data type at  the end of the column name.  For instance date_of_birth_datetime or amount_refunded_decimal.  To me this just feels wrong, but I can't seem to come up with a good reason to try and persuade him to abandon this convention.  The only reason I can come up with is that it takes up 5-10 characters to include this data type which can be used to create more meaningful column names.  Can anyone help me out, or is this a good practice and I need to correct my way of thinking?  If so, why?

Comment: There's not a definitive answer - you could argue that it clutters the name, that the data type is easily discoverable, that the name should represent the _intent_, not the _storage mechanism_, that the data type is often implied by th ename (e.g. Name is always a string), etc.

Comment: Also DBAs should not have the authority to enforce naming standards _unless they impact the stability or performance of the system_.  That's a designer's job, not a DBAs.

Comment: You could also use a [reductio ad absurdum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum) - what about unicode? what about decimals of varying scales and precisions?  what about the _length_ of a string?

Comment: This sounds just as useless as prefixing all tables with `tbl_`

Comment: @HunterNelson . . . I am guessing that almost everyone here is going to disagree with the DBA (you can look at sample code on this and other sites to see that such conventions are not prevalent).  I find it particularly problematic in Oracle, because of the limit of 32 characters in a name.  And it makes changing the type of a column awkward.  It seems like a sophomoric solution to a problem (whatever that might be) that has other solutions.  Yet, these seem to be opinions and hence outside the scope of Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I suspected that some opinions would be given, however stack overflow has tons of these questions, and I always find their discussion valuable even if no concrete answer arises.  I suspect it will be closed by a moderator eventually, however there was no existing question (that I saw) and I think it was worth opening the discussion.

Comment: Every IDE like SQL Developer or TOAD shows such information instantly anyway. Changing a data type drives you to change code in your application, PL/SQL code, views, etc. Other attributes like "NOT NULL", "VIRTUAL" or "used by an index" might be much more important, however in this case you would loose any freedom to name your columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DBA is including this for troubleshooting purposes should there be anything to come up later down the road instead of just looking in SSMS details. Seems to me this is not a good practice especially if your applications on beyond the intranet... giving a hacker another tool set easily to get into the system as an example.

I personally would not include the datatype in my SQL DB's. http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Creating-SQL-Server-columns-A-best-practices-guide

Comment: Gave this a +1 because this article mentions creating a data dictionary which I think would be a good alternative solution to including data types within the column name.